# (US) What is the deduction for gifts of appreciated stock with restricted registration rights?

Tags: united-states, tax-deduction, capital-gain, charitable-contributions

I have appreciated stock that I am allowed to give away to charitable transferees, but those transferees will have restricted registration rights for 12 months. They cannot sell the stock for 12 months.

Assuming a qualified transferee agrees to accept the transfer before the end of 2014, can I still deduct the fair market value at time of transfer for 2014's AGI?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, which is, of course: "it depends." In general a professional appraisal is required for donation of non-liquid assets. However for assets with a defined market value there is usually just a small discount applied to the market price at transfer, something on the order of 5%.